# Change network proxy settings in via commandline in Mac OS X Lion

Tags: command-line, proxy, osx-lion, system-preferences

I'm looking for the configuration file that keeps track of the Network Proxy settings in OS X. Is it stored in a `.plist` file?

Specifically I'd like to programmatically modify the "Bypass proxy settings for these Hosts & Domains" field.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the networksetup command to get and set the proxy bypasses. Excerpts from the man page:

```
networksetup
  [-getproxybypassdomains networkservice]
  [-setproxybypassdomains networkservice domain1 [domain2] [...]]


  -getproxybypassdomains networkservice
     Displays Bypass Domain Names for <networkservice>.

   -setproxybypassdomains networkservice domain1 [domain2] [...]
     Set the Bypass Domain Name Servers for <networkservice> to <domain1> [domain2] [...].
```

Any
     number of Domain Name servers can be specified. Specify "Empty" for  to clear all Domain
     Name entries.

Comment: For the uninformed, you can display a complete list of options with usage instructions by entering the command `networksetup` with no parameters. Also, to display a list of names of each available `<networkservice>` enter the command `networksetup -listallnetworkservices`.

Answer (score 10):

You can change your MAC OS proxy using below command:-

```
networksetup -setwebproxy "Your network service name(Airport,Ethernet etc..)" host port
```

example:-

```
networksetup -setwebproxy "Ethernet Adaptor (en0)" 122.176.70.186 80
```

Simply run this command on the terminal.

Answer (score 7):

The settings are stored in `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist`. I found out that you have to match up the `Sets` field with the `NetworkServices` field. They look like GUIDs.

[image: preferences]